# Verify id_token Using a Google API Client Library in PHP

Tags: php, api

I already have the id_token and it works fine for Calling the token info endpoint but the Google API Client Library for PHP return no result on verifyIdToken() I can't figure out why as no error is thrown any idea on how to fix this?

```
include_once('google-api-php-client-2.1.1/vendor/autoload.php');
 $id_token = trim($_GET['id_token']);
$CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXX-o36ncvcpbpo9uiiejb0qXXXXX8820tom.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);

$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
if ($payload) {
    echo 'your id: ' . $userid = $payload['sub'];
    // If request specified a G Suite domain:
    //$domain = $payload['hd'];
} else {
    // Invalid ID token
    echo 'invalid token';
}
```

At the end it still print invalid token